# how to query bank activity with sage sdata service

Tags: php, web-services, sage-line-50, sdata

I am looking at sage 50 sdata webservice I am able to list all bank accounts and I am able to list customer bank account ect but I can not figure out how to list the activity of one of the bank accounts say the the cash account.
I am hitting the following endpoint that list only bank accounts "http://localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/bankAccountOpCo" I have looked through all the available adapters so I think it must be a query made to the webservice that gives the list of activity for an individual bank account, can anyone adivise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage is like a plant and all plants need a seed in this case the seed or should I say table you need to search is tradingActivities it is the root of sage accounts it what accounts call the audit trail my suggestion is to look at the financials module and use the report builder to see how sage would generate the data you require because all data stems from here. You may want to try something like`localhost:5493/sdata/accounts50/GCRM/-/tradingActivities?where=accountReferance eq"1201"&format=json`I hope this helps.

Comment: you may like to check this out "https://github.com/Sage/SData-2.0/blob/master/JSON%20formatted%20SData%20responses%20-%20v101.pdf"

Comment: Thank you Circleshair but tradingActivities is incomplete I need to query tradingActivies and receipts endpoints from what i can see but how?

Comment: I have been advise by the team at sage that due to  audit split not being exposed in sdata so you can not completely obtain all the values of the bank account for a particular nominal account as they are held in the audit split you can however make a request for audit split to be exposed in the next release by asking on https://github.com/Sage/SData-2.0/issues or login in to your online sage account 'https://communities.sage.co.uk/ideas/i/sage_50_accounts' and asking there i hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Circleshair I already have made the request for audit split to be exposed